# Creating responsive 3 x 3 gallery box

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

Hello I am trying to create a flex grid which has 3 by 3 image gallery which is responsive,

Currently this is going on a wordpress page and this is the code to my image using openseadragon.
So I need this image:

to appear three times next to each other and three on the bottom, I will update the images and add more image boxes once i get the correct layout. I need to add a little bit of padding underneath each row too.

Thank you.

```html
<style>
/* assumes reset with box-sizing:border-box; is in effect */
.gallery ul {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    position:relative;
    left:-1em;
    /*
        uncomment these if centering desired
        max-width:63em;
        margin:0 auto;
    */
}
.gallery li {
    flex:1 1 auto;
    padding:1em;
    margin:0 0 1em 1em;
    width:26%;
    max-width:20em;
}
.gallery a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
   
.gallery li img {
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto 1em;
}
</style>
<section class="gallery">
    <h2>Describe this Gallery</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
<div id="materials-01581" class="suarrmaterials-zoomable-image" style="height:400px; width:400px;" data-image="2013/02/DSC_0158-1-scaled.jpg"></div>
            <p>
                Some text about the image
            </p>
        </li>
        <!-- repeat the above list-item here -->
        <li>
<div id="materials-01581" class="suarrmaterials-zoomable-image" style="height:400px; width:400px;" data-image="2013/02/DSC_0158-1-scaled.jpg"></div>
            <p>
                Some text about the image
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
<div id="materials-01581" class="suarrmaterials-zoomable-image" style="height:400px; width:400px;" data-image="2013/02/DSC_0158-1-scaled.jpg"></div>
            <p>
                Some text about the image
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
<!-- .gallery --></section>
```

Comment: Hi, could you give us an example from what you already tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: <html><title>KING + KING LIBRARY MATERIALS</title>
<body>
<div id="secondary-banner" class="header-secondary">Our materials collection is classified into 7 large categories</div>
<p>Click on the image to view the material in-depth.</p>
<div class="categories">
 <a href="#">
    <h3>Composites (CP)</h3>
    <p>Categorized under 06-WOOD, PLASTICS AND COMPOSITES.</p>
<figure class="wp-block-image"><img src="https://suarrmaterials-test.syr.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/I1-e1589313852600.jpg"/></figure>
 </a></html>

Comment: Could you place this inside a working snippet, you can find how-to on the page I mentioned earlier? A direct link to the how-to is: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do#answer-358993 . This way you can also test if your example does something. ;)

Comment: I added the code to the snippet

Comment: I have added the images in, what size should it be to appear nicely with the text, bc the text shows up good but then the images appear like this
https://ibb.co/zr53xgM

Answer (score 0):

I've created 2 sets of examples, they both are a responsive layout. I would recommend settings a breakpoint when the layout 'breaks' and set them to 1 or 2 columns.

1. Images with the same exact aspect ratio.

   - Pro: texts under images will align with the others on the same row, even while scaling.
   - Con: images will be cut-off when the original image aspect ratio is to different from the wrapper aspect ratio which contains the image (landscape vs portrait for example).
2. Images with different aspect ratio's

   - Pro: images will keep their aspect ratio and won't be cut-off.
   - Con: texts under the images won't align with the others on the same row.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery {
  /* Negative margin = the padding of the wrapper. This ensures the boxes aligning against the left and right side of the container. Uncomment when this is not wanted. */
  /* 
  margin-left: -1rem;
  margin-right: -1rem;
  */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

  
@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    
    .gallery {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}


/* Wrapper is needed to create extra space between gallery boxes in case a background color is needed. */

.gallery_image-wrapper {
  padding: 1rem;
  min-width: 8rem;
  /* Don't Grow, Do Shrink, Base size of 33.33% */
  flex: 0 1 33.33%;
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    
    .gallery_image-wrapper {
      flex: 1 1 100%;
    }
}

.gallery_image {}

.gallery_image-description {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.gallery_image-graphic {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  /* Add small spacing between image and description */
  padding: 0 0 56.25% 0;
  /* Ratio trick to make sure the images are the same size. */
  background-size: cover;
  /* Make sure the image is alway filling/covering the box */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.gallery_image-graphic-inline {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Gallery Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Example 1 - As background images</h2>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery_image-wrapper">
      <div class="gallery_image">
        <div class="gallery_image-graphic" style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/750x500.png?text=Image%20Example');"></div>
        <div class="gallery_image-description">A random text about the image.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_image-wrapper">
      <div class="gallery_image">
        <div class="gallery_image-graphic" style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/750x500.png?text=Image%20Example');"></div>
        <div class="gallery_image-description">If the image contains relevant information</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_image-wrapper">
      <div class="gallery_image">
        <div class="gallery_image-graphic" style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/750x500.png?text=Image%20Example');"></div>
        <div class="gallery_image-description">make sure to add it to your description.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2>Example 2 - Inline images</h2>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery_image-wrapper">
      <div class="gallery_image">
        <img class="gallery_image-graphic-inline" src="https://via.placeholder.com/750x500.png?text=Image%20Example" />
        <div class="gallery_image-description">Image example 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_image-wrapper">
      <div class="gallery_image">
        <img class="gallery_image-graphic-inline" src="https://via.placeholder.com/750x600.png?text=Image%20Example" />
        <div class="gallery_image-description">Image example 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery_image-wrapper">
      <div class="gallery_image">
        <img class="gallery_image-graphic-inline" src="https://via.placeholder.com/750x400.png?text=Image%20Example" />
        <div class="gallery_image-description">Image example 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update**

Just in case it is a viewport meta issue, can you check if you have the following in your head?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: HI Dave I tried your way which is create but when i shrink the window, I it overlapps one another, how do i make it so its a flex box and goes underneath one another... please see the example on https://suarrmaterials-test.syr.edu/landlok-2/

Comment: Hi, you external links doesn't work for me (timeout). I've tested my example in Firefox, Chrome and Edge. It works in all three (latest version). Which browser + version are you using? At which size/resolution are you checking your code? In smaller screen you need to reshape the column layout to 2 or 1 because of the shortage of space (see answer).